# Change default python version in idle (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, default, python-idle

So, I'd like to have Python 2.7.6 when I open the idle (that is the one pre-installed on Ubuntu); instead, the idle opens with the one that I have installed (2.7.5).
How can I do that?

Comment: When you run Idle, you actually run a particular version of Python, telling it to run the corresponding version of Idle.  Ubuntu really should be allowing you to install and run 2.7.9, which is months old and which has security upgrades and an improved Idle.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

and see the `update-alternatives` man page. If Ubuntu does not offer the alternatives automatically, you'll have to add them yourself, e.g.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.5 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.5 20
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it tells me that there are "no alternatives for python".

Comment: Updated. Please refer to the man-page or google, if you encounter more troubles.